# Is there a clever way to the do the following?

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Is ther any clear way of doing the following in one SQL (PL) code? :)

What I have in the tables is the following:

**CONTACT_TBL (HEADER)**

| CONTRACT_ID | BEGIN_DATE | END_DATE | TOT_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 13-MAY-16 | 12-MAY-34 | 100 |
| 456 | 13-JAN-14 | 12-DEC-25 | 300 |
| 789 | 13-SEP-14 | 12-OCT-34 | 700 |

**CONTRACT_ACTIVTY (DETAIL)**

| CONTRACT_ID | SEQNUM | END_DATE | AMOUNT | COMMENTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 12-MAY-19 | 25 | 25 - Initial Expiration |
| 123 | 2 | 12-MAY-24 | 25 | 25 |
| 123 | 3 | 12-MAY-29 | 25 | 25 |
| 123 | 4 | 12-MAY-34 | 25 | 25 - End of Contract |

What we need is to populate for each row:

1. BEGIN_DATE

- For SEQNUM #1 - BEGIN_DATE is always CONTACT_TBL.BEGIN_DATE (in this case 13-MAY-15, a 3 year span)
- For SEQNUM #2 to N - BEGIN_DATE is 1 day more than previous row's  END_DATE (in this case 12-MAY-19 + 1 = 13-MAY-19, all 5 year spans)

2. Mark the row 'Active' if the SYSDATE is between BEGIN_DATE and END_DATE (in this case it's Row #2)

| CONTRACT_ID | SEQNUM | BEGIN_DATE | END_DATE | AMOUNT | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 13-MAY-16 | 12-MAY-19 | 25 |  |
| 123 | 2 | 13-MAY-19 | 12-MAY-24 | 25 | Active |
| 123 | 3 | 13-MAY-24 | 12-MAY-29 | 25 |  |
| 123 | 4 | 13-MAY-29 | 12-MAY-34 | 25 |  |

Comment: What database are you using? You've tagged two different ones.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question? -> Write a title that summarizes the specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Write%20a%20title%20that%20summarizes%20the%20specific%20problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*N.B. This answer assumes the db is Oracle*

This can be done by using [`LAG`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAG.html#GUID-68081CD0-72BE-4C0A-AA6B-AD39FFA7BCF2) to find the date from the previous row.

`LAG` can accept 3 parameters, the first of which is the column whose value you want to find from the previous row, the second is how many rows to go back each time (default is 1), and the third is what to display if there is no previous row found.

In your case, you want to default to the begin_date from the `contact_tbl` if there is no previous row to the first row in the `contract_activity` table, so you need to join the two tables as well, like so:

```
WITH   contact_tbl AS (SELECT 123 contract_id, to_date('13/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') begin_date, to_date('12/05/2034', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 100 tot_amount FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 456 contract_id, to_date('13/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') begin_date, to_date('12/05/2034', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 100 tot_amount FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 789 contract_id, to_date('13/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') begin_date, to_date('12/05/2034', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 100 tot_amount FROM dual),
 contract_activity AS (SELECT 123 contract_id, 1 seqnum, to_date('12/05/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 25 amount, '25 - Initial Expiration' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 123 contract_id, 2 seqnum, to_date('12/05/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 25 amount, '25' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 123 contract_id, 3 seqnum, to_date('12/05/2029', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 25 amount, '25' comments FROM dual UNION ALL
                       SELECT 123 contract_id, 4 seqnum, to_date('12/05/2034', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date, 25 amount, '25 - End of Contract' comments FROM dual),
-- end of creating subqueries to mimic your tables
  contract_details AS (SELECT ca.contract_id,
                              ca.seqnum,
                              LAG(ca.end_date + 1, 1, c.begin_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ca.contract_id ORDER BY seqnum) begin_date,
                              ca.end_date,
                              ca.amount
                       FROM   contact_tbl c
                              INNER JOIN contract_activity ca ON c.contract_id = ca.contract_id)
SELECT contract_id,
       seqnum,
       begin_date,
       end_date,
       amount,
       CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date THEN 'Active' END status
FROM   contract_details;

CONTRACT_ID     SEQNUM BEGIN_DATE  END_DATE        AMOUNT STATUS
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ------
        123          1 13/05/2016  12/05/2019          25 
        123          2 13/05/2019  12/05/2024          25 Active
        123          3 13/05/2024  12/05/2029          25 
        123          4 13/05/2029  12/05/2034          25
```

Your `status` column is a simple case expression, but since it refers to the calculated begin_date, rather than repeating the calculation, I did the begin_date calculation in one subquery, and then referenced that in the outer query.

Note how I used `TRUNC(sysdate)` instead of just `sysdate` in the case expression for the `status` - DATEs in Oracle have a time component (which defaults to midnight if you don't specify the time), so if you ran the query any time between `12/05/2024 00:00:01` and `12/05/2024 23:59:59`, your query wouldn't return a status of `Active` for the second row if you used `sysdate`. You need to explicitly truncate `sysdate` to midnight in order for the comparison to work.

Comment: Thank you so very very much!!!!  This is excatly what I was looking for.  You are a genius.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below snippet serve the purpose.

```
 DECLARE

   CURSOR cur_contracts IS
   SELECT
     *
   FROM
     CONTACT_TBL
   ORDER BY
     CONTRACT_ID;

   CURSOR cur_contracts_act(contact_id NUMBER) IS
   SELECT
     *
   FROM
     CONTRACT_ACTIVTY
   ORDER BY
     CONTRACT_ID,
     SEQNUM;
     
   l_ca_begin_date DATE;
   l_ca_status VARCHAR2(10);
   l_prev_rec_end_date DATE;
   
BEGIN
   FOR i IN cur_contracts
   LOOP
      contract_activity_seq := 0;
      FOR j IN cur_contracts_act (i.CONTRACT_ID)
      LOOP
         contract_activity_seq := contract_activity_seq + 1;
         IF (contract_activity_seq = 1) THEN 
            l_ca_begin_date := i.begin_date;
         ELSE 
            l_ca_begin_date := l_prev_rec_end_date + 1;
         END IF;
         IF SYSDATE BETWEEN l_ca_begin_date AND j.end_date THEN 
            l_ca_status := 'Active';
         ELSE 
            l_ca_status := NULL;
         END IF;
         
         l_prev_rec_end_date := j.end_date;
         UPDATE CONTRACT_ACTIVTY
         SET BEGIN_DATE = l_ca_begin_date,
             status = l_ca_status
         WHERE CURRENT OF cur_contracts_act;
         END LOOP;
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN raise_application_error(
    -20001,
    'An error was encountered - ' || SQLCODE || ' -ERROR- ' || SQLERRM
  );
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi Sankar - this looks great!  One thing I forgot to mention is that I am not allowed to update any tables. :(  The output should be in a a SQL view.

Comment: Try to dump data to temp tables and try fetching from there.